# Where can I find MessageBox Control for ASP.net?

Tags: asp.net, messagebox

Where can I find a MessageBox Control for my ASP.net web application? It has to be free and simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit, you can use its [ModalPopup extender](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx). Alternatively, jQuery [has a plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-message/) you could use.

Comment: How can I use the ModalPopup?

Comment: @Tassisto: There is an example on the link I gave you. If that doesn't help, [here is another](http://www.karpach.com/ModalPopupExtender-Example.htm). You'll find dozens of other examples on a Google search.

Answer (score 0):

How's this for a poor man's solution? :)

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript: if(window.confirm('really?')) { alert('you said ok'); }; return false;">click me</a>
```

Comment: I need it for exception handling, it has to be a control. To modify it at code-behind

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [jQueryUI Message Box](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/message).